# What is needed to make Payflow Pro Recurring Donations work?

Tags: payment-processor, recurring-contributions

CiviCRM supports comes with PayFlow Pro but it doesn't support recurring payments.  I looked at the code and there's code for recurring.  What is needed to finish this part of the payment processor?  An IPN segment?  I already know that it will take time, money and developers.  I'm looking for what these items would be used for.

Comment: To be clear re: the bounty: I already know that http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Payment+Processors says: No code written but processor can support it.  I know Lobo's quoted 20 hours of work.  I'd like details on the exact work.

Comment: I saw that there was code to support recurring payments, too. I have a sneaking suspicion that the recurring check-box on the contribution page is hard-coded to display only for Authorize.net and PayPal Pro, but I haven't dug in to find that bit in core.

Comment: No, each payment processor can specify if they handle recurring or not (stripe and sepa for instance offer recurring).

Answer (score 1):

This issue from 2009 seems to be the one to add payflow into the core:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-5536

per Eileen comment:

> "Although the code is there to upload recurring transactions the
>   customer opted not to complete the recurring payment side of things so
>   this should be turned off in the payment_processor_type table for now.
>
> (code works but on-going querying of outcomes in incomplete)."

I would suggest you add a comment to this issue or contact Eileen on chat.civicrm if you want to know more about what's missing or an estimate of the number of hours need to make the recurring happen